# How to properly package a block plugin

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor

I've created a little WordPress block, starting from the `npx @wordpress/create-block` template. All is well and good, but I need to fix the packaging process.

The main plugin file includes a couple of php files:

```
define( '__ROOT__', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );

require_once( __ROOT__ . 'src/testimonial-pages.php' );
require_once( __ROOT__ . 'src/block.php' );
```

The problem is, `npm run plugin-zip` does not include those files in the zip archive.

According to the [plugin-zip docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-scripts/#plugin-zip),

> In the case where the plugin author wants to customize the files
> included in the zip file, they can provide the files field in the
> package.json file as documented in the [npm-packlist package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-packlist)

which it does, but isn't the desired behavior. It includes the files specified, but also some additional cruft (e.g., the `package.json` file), and not all of the original files included by `npm run plugin-zip` if I don't add a "files" section to `package.json`.

Example:

```
% npm run plugin-zip
Using Plugin Handbook best practices to discover files:

  Adding `cwr-testimonial-block.php`.
  Adding `readme.txt`.
  Adding `build/block.json`.
  Adding `build/index.asset.php`.
  Adding `build/index.css`.
  Adding `build/index.js`.
  Adding `build/slider.asset.php`.
  Adding `build/slider.css`.
  Adding `build/slider.js`.
  Adding `build/style-index.css`.
```

then if I add `"files": [ "src/*php" ]` to `package.json`:

```
% npm run plugin-zip
Using the `files` field from `package.json` to detect files:

  Adding `build/index.js`.
  Adding `package.json`.
  Adding `src/block.php`.
  Adding `src/testimonial-pages.php`.
  Adding `readme.txt`.
```

So, I guess what I want is to extend "Plugin Handbook best practices" to include my required files. (or, alternatively, make whatever changes I need to make such that my plugin conforms to said best practices (which I can't actually find in the [Plugin Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/), but maybe I'm missing something)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a folder named `includes` in the root of your plugin folder; and place your additional php files inside of there. They (andchild folders and files) should then be copied over with `plugin-zip`.

If you have a php file with the same name as your plugin in your plugin's root folder; that will also copy over as well. (e.g. your plugin is named `super-rad-explosion`; `plugin-zip` will also copy over`super-rad-explosion.php` in the root folder of the zip).